# How do I commit/push my build folder into another git repository and not into the main repository?

Tags: reactjs, git, github, git-submodules, glitch-framework

So, I've recently made a React app which I have posted on GitHub. However, I would like to post the output (`build` folder after I run `npm run build`) to a Glitch application. Since all Glitch applications have a `git` repository, I thought that would be the best way to go about doing this. Here is my desired structure:

- My main `git` repo, which pushes to GitHub. **This repository ignores the `build` folder.**
- Another "sub" `git` repository, which only pushes the contents of `build` to Glitch.

I've seen people using submodules, but I can't figure out how to make my main `git` repo ignore the `build` folder and have the submodule just push the `build` folder.

I'm also confused on how to setup a submodule in general, so an example/explanation for that as well would be appreciated.

~ Ayush

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure that you *want* a submodule here, but submodules will let you do what you are describing.  Submodules are tricky, though.  There's a reason people call them *sob*-modules.

## Long

First, it will help a great deal if you get your definitions—actors and actions—straight:

- A *repository* does not push anything.  It's just a collection of commits (plus some names; see the last point below).
- Git (the software suite) creates and manipulates repositories, including the commits inside them.
- The `git push` command pushes *commits*.
- A *commit* is a thingy (technically, a *commit object*, but people use the term pretty loosely, hence the loose "thingy" term here ) with the following features:

  - It has a unique hash ID.
  - It stores *files*.  Note that commits do not store *folders*, just *files*.  These files have path names that include embedded slashes (always forward slashes, even if you extract the commit's files on a Windows sytem with their backward slashes).  This eventually becomes important later, but if you like, you can think of them as folders-full-of-files, as long as you remember that [Git can't store an *empty folder* properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/115983/1256452) (because it only stores *files*).  The files are stored *as* full snapshots, although they get compressed and—importantly—de-duplicated across all commits in a repository.  So, the fact that typically some new commit re-uses 30,000 files from some previous commit doesn't matter: the re-used files take no space, because they're literally re-used.
  - It stores *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  This includes stuff like who made the commit and when, and a log message, and so on; and, crucial for Git's own operation, it also includes the raw hash ID of some set of earlier commits.  Most commits store just one earlier-commit hash ID, which we (and Git) call the *parent*.  This is how history works, in a Git repository: each commit *remembers its parent*.
  - It is completely read-only.  No part of any commit can ever be changed.  (This is what allows the de-duplication, and a lot of other Git magic.)
- A repository also contains names—such as branch and tag names—that allow Git to *find* commits.  This works by having one name store exactly *one* hash ID.  For branch names, that stored hash ID is, by definition, the *last commit in the branch*.  Since commits store parent hash IDs, Git can work backwards from whichever commit we decide to call "last in branch `X`": `X~1` is the second-to-last in `X`, `X~2` is the third-to-last, and so on.

The act of adding a new commit to a branch consists of the following steps:

1. You *check out* that commit (with `git checkout` or `git switch`) by checking out that *branch* (with the same command), so that this is now the *current branch*.  This action fills in both Git's index—which holds your *proposed next commit*—and your *working tree*, where Git copies out all the files into a usable form.  The internal, de-duplicated form is generally unusable to everything except Git itself.
2. You do some stuff in your working tree.  Git has zero control or influence over this part, a lot of the time, since you'll be using your own editor or compiler or whatever.  You can use Git commands here and then Git will be able to see what you did, but mostly, Git doesn't have to care, because we move on to step 3:
3. You run `git add`.  This instructs Git to take a look at the updated working tree files.  Git will copy these updated files back into Git's index (aka the *staging area*), in their updated form, re-compressing and de-duplicating them and generally making them *ready for the next commit*.
4. You run `git commit`.  This packages up new metadata—your name, the current date and time, a log message, and so on—and adds the *current commit's hash ID* to make up the metadata for the new commit.  The new commit's parent will thus be the current commit.  Git then snapshots *everything in the index at this time* (which is why `git checkout` filled it in, in step 1, and then `git add` updated it in step 3), along with the metadata, to make the new commit.  This gives the new commit its new hash ID, which is actually just a cryptographic checksum of the entire data set here.

   It's at this point that the magic happens: `git commit` *writes the new commit's hash ID into the current branch name*.  So now, the last commit on the branch is your new commit.  **This is how a branch grows,** one commit at a time.  No *existing* commit changes—none *can* change—but the new commit points back to what *was* the last commit, and is now the second-to-last commit.  The *branch name* **moves**.

You really need to have all of these down pretty cold to make submodules work, because submodules actually *use* all of this stuff, but then violate some rules.  Now it starts to get tricky.  We also need to look more closely at `git push`, just for a moment.

#### `git push`: cross-connecting one Git repository with another

Making a new Git commit, in some Git repository, just makes a new snapshot-plus-metadata.  The next trick is to get that commit into some *other* Git repository.

If we start with two otherwise-identical Git repositories, each has some set of commits and some branch names identifying the same *last* commit:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--branch-name   [in Repo A]
```

and the same in Repo B.  But then, over in Repo A, we do:

```
git checkout branch-name
<do stuff>
git commit
```

which causes repo A to contain:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- branch-name
```

(I get lazy and don't bother drawing the commit-to-commit arrows correctly here).  New commit `I`—`I`, like `H` and `G` and `F`, stands in for some big ugly random-looking hash ID—points back to existing commit `H`.  You might even make more than one new commit:

```
...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- branch-name
```

Now you run `git push origin branch-name`, to send your new commits, in your repository, back to the "origin" repo (which we were calling "repo B" before, but let's call it `origin` now).

Your Git software suite ("your Git") calls up theirs.  Your Git lists out the hash ID of your latest commit, i.e., commit `J`.  Their Git checks in their repository, to see if they have `J`, by hash ID.  They don't (because you just made it).  So their Git tells your Git: *OK, gimme!*  Your Git is now obligated to offer `J`'s parent `I`.  They check and don't have `I` either, so they ask for that one too.  Your Git is now obligated to offer commit `H`.  They check and—hey!—this time they *do* have commit `H` already, so they say: *no thanks, I have that one already*.

Your Git now knows not only that you must send *commits* `J` and `I`, but also *which files* they already have.  They have commit `H`, so they must have commit `G` too, and commit `F`, and so on.  They have *all the de-duplicated files* that go with those commits.  So your Git software suite can now compute a *minimal* set of stuff to send them so that they can *reconstruct* commits `I-J`.

Your Git does so; that's the "counting" and "compressing" and so on that you see.  Their Git receives this stuff, unpacks it, and adds the new commits to *their* repository.  They now have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- branch-name
            \
             I--J
```

in their Git repository.  Now we hit a really tricky bit: **How does a Git, in general, *find* a commit?**  The answer is always, ultimately, *by its hash ID*—but that just brings another question, which is: how does a Git find a hash ID?  They *look* random.

We already said this earlier though: a Git (the software suite) often finds some specific commit in some specific repository through the use of a *branch name*.  The branch name `branch-name`, in *your* repository, finds the *last* commit, which is now `J`.  We'd like the *same name* in *their* repository to find the same last commit.

So, your Git software now asks their Git to set *their* repository's branch name `branch-name` to identify commit `J`.  They will do this *if* you are *allowed* to do this.  The "allowed" part can get arbitrarily complicated—sites like GitHub and Bitbucket add all kinds of permissions and rules here—but if we assume that it's OK, and that they'll do that, then *they* will end up with:

```
...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- branch-name
```

in *their* repository, and your Git repository and their Git repository will be in sync again, at least for this particular branch name.

So that's how `git push` normally works: you make new commits, adding them on to the end of *your* branch, and then you send your new commits to some other Git, and ask their software to add the same commits to the end of a branch of the *same name* in *their* repository.  (Whew!)

#### Submodules

A submodule, in Git, is little more than *two separate, mostly-independent* Git repositories.  This of course needs a lot of explanation:

- Why are they only "mostly" independent?  (What does that even mean?)
- If they're *little more*, what *more* are they?

First, like any repository, a submodule repository is a collection of commits, each with a unique hash ID.  We—or Git at least—like to refer to one of the two repositories as the *superproject* and the other as the *submodule*.  Both of these start with the letter S, which is annoying, and both words are long and klunky, so here I'll use **R** (in bold like this) as the superproject **R**epository, and **S** as the **S**ubmodule.

(Side note: the hash IDs in **R** and **S** are independent from each other.  Git tries pretty hard—and usually succeeds—at making hash IDs *globally* unique across *every* Git repository everywhere in the universe.  So there's no need to worry about "contaminating" **R** with **S** IDs or vice versa.  In any case we can just treat every commit hash ID as if it's totally unique.  Normally, with a normal non-**R** non-**S** repository, we don't even have to *care* about IDs, as we just use names.  But submodules make you have to be more aware of the IDs.)

What makes **R** a *superproject* in the first place is that it lists raw hash IDs from **S**.  It also has to list *instructions:* if we've done a `git clone` of **R**, we don't even have a clone of **S** yet.  So **R** needs to contain the *instructions* so that your Git software can make a clone of **S**.

The instructions you give to `git clone` are pretty simple:

```
git clone <url> <path>
```

(where the *`path`* part is even optional, but here, **R** will always specify a path—using those forward slash path names we mentioned earlier).  This set of instructions goes into a file named `.gitmodules`.  The `git submodule add` command will set up this file in **R** for you.  It's important to use it, to set up the `.gitmodules` file.  Git will still make a submodule even if you *don't* set this up, but without the cloning instructions, the submodule won't actually *work*.

Note that there's no proper place to put authentication (user and password names) in here.  That's a generic submodule issue.  (You *can* put them in as plaintext in the `.gitmodules` file, but **don't do it**, it's a very bad idea, they're not encrypted or protected.)  As long as you have open access to cloning the submodule, it doesn't normally present any real problem.  If you don't, you'll have to solve this problem somehow.

In any case, you will need, just once, to run:

```
git submodule add ...
```

(filling in the `...` part) in what will thus become superproject **R**, so as to create the `.gitmodules` file.  You then need to commit the resulting `.gitmodules` file, so that people who clone **R** and check out a commit that *contains* that file, get that file, so that their Git software can run the `git clone` command to create **S** on their system.

You'll also need to put **S** somewhere they can clone it.  This, of course, means that first you need to create a Git repository to hold **S**.  You do this the way you make any Git repository:

```
git init
```

or:

```
git clone
```

(locally, on your machine) along with whatever you do on whatever hosting site that creates the repository there.

Now that you have a local repository **S**, you need to put some commit(s) into it.  What goes into these commits?

Well, you already said that you'd like your **R** to have a `build/` directory (folder) in it, but not actually store any of the built files in any of the commits made in **R**.  This is where submodules actually work.  A submodule, in **R**, for **S**, works by saying: *create me a folder here, then clone the submodule into the folder*.  Or, if the submodule repository already exists—as it will when you're setting all this up in the first place, with you just now having created `S`—you simply put that entire repository into your working tree for **R**, under the name `build`.

Note that `build/.git` will exist in **R**'s working tree at this point.  That's because a Git repository hides all the Git files in the `.git` directory (folder) at the top level of the working tree.  So your new, empty **S** repository consists of just a `.git/` containing Git files.

You can now run that `git submodule add` command in **R**, because now you have the submodule in place:

```
git submodule add <url> build
```

(You might want to wait just a little bit, but you *can* definitely do it at this point—and this is the earliest point at which you can do it, since up until now, **S** didn't exist or was not in the right place yet.)

You can now *fill the `build/` directory* that lives in **R**'s working tree with files, e.g., by running `npm run build`, or whatever it is that populates the `build/` directory.  Then you can:

```
(cd build; git add .)
```

or equivalent, so as to add the build output in **S**.  You can now create the first commit *in* **S**, or maybe as the second commit in **S** if you like to create a `README.md` and `LICENSE` and such as your initial commit.  You can now have branches in **S** as well, since you now have at least one commit in **S**.

Now that you're back in **R** though, it's time to `git add build`—or, if you chose to delay it, run that first `git submodule add`.  In the future you'll use `git add build`.  This directs the Git that is manipulating the *index / staging-area for **R*** to enter the *repository* **S** and run:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

to find the *raw hash ID* of the *current commit* in **S**.

The superproject's Git repository's index now acquires a new *gitlink* entry.  A gitlink entry is like a regular file, except that instead of `git checkout` checking it out *as* a file, it provides a *raw hash ID*.  That's basically all it is: a pathname—in this case, `build/`—and a raw hash ID.

This gitlink is like one of those read-only, compressed, and de-duplicated files that goes in a commit.  It's just that instead of storing *file data*, it stores a *commit hash ID*.  That hash ID is that of some commit in **S**, not some commit in **R** itself.  But now that you've updated the *index* (or *staging area*) for **R**, you will need to make a new *commit* in **R**.  The new commit will contain any updated files, plus the right hash ID for **S**, as found just now by the `git add` you ran (or that `git submodule add` ran for you).

The *next commit you make in **R** (not in S)* will list the hash ID of the *current* commit in **S**.  So once you've committed the built files in **S**, you can `git add` them in **R** and `git commit` in **R**.

#### The last and trickiest part

Now comes the last part, which—if you thought all of the above was complicated and tricky—is the trickiest:

- You have to `git push` the submodule commit in **S** so that it's generally available.  In general, you *should* do this first, though you don't actually have to.
- Then you have to `git push` the superproject commit in **R** so that others can get it.  When others get this commit from the other clone of **R**, they'll be able to see the right hash ID from **S**.
- Then, if someone else—let's say your co-worker Bob—wants to get both the built files *and* the sources, they have to:

  - Obtain your new **R** commit.
  - Instruct their Git to *check out* the new **R** commit.
  - Instruct their Git to use the new checked out **R** commit to run `git fetch` in **S** so as to obtain the new **S** commit.
  - Instruct their Git to actually enter their clone of **S** and `git checkout` the correct commit.

  They can do this all at once with `git checkout --recursive`, or set the recursive checkout option.  Note what can go wrong though:
- They might obtain your new **R** commit and check it out, but forget to update their **S** at all.
- Or, they might obtain your new **R** commit and check it out and then try to check out the new commit *in* **S** without first running `git fetch` in their clone of **S**, so that they don't *have* the new commit.
- Or, they might remember everything they should do, but someone forgot to *push* the new **S** commit to the shared repository people can get it from.  They'll get an error about their submodule Git being unable to find the requested commit.

You can see how this can get pretty messy.  It's very easy for the various separate commits to get de-synchronized in various ways.  Once you have the procedures down, and have scripts around everything that make sure that all the steps happen at the right times, it can work pretty well.  But there are many ways for things to go wrong.

Comment: +1 Wow, this is a huge help! Thank you for your amazing explanation!!! However, there is just one thing I want missing from this. In your explanation, you explain how **S** can be obtained *from* **R**. However, I would like to make **S** "hidden", including the repository URL (that pushes **S** to Glitch), and all the actual files, so it's like it was never there. Is there any way that I can do this with Git Submodules?

Comment: Also, at the start, you say "I'm not entirely sure that you want a submodule here". So, what should I use instead? Should I try putting the `build` folder in my `.gitignore` (which it already is) and then make a new `git` repository inside `build`? Or, is there another method you were thinking about?

Comment: No: the fact that there is a gitlink is plain to see in the commit, because the gitlink is there. You *can* leave out the cloning *instructions*, so that you have a gitlink that can't be cloned—which produces what I sometimes call a *half-assed submodule*. They're annoying, though, because now you have this weird gitlink that causes problems. (To make one of these, skip the `git submodule add` step.)

Comment: Instead of having a submodule, consider just having a bunch of tar files, or other archives, of particular builds. Any time you have a *released* version of something, you build the release archive and stick it somewhere obtainable, for those who don't want to build it themselves.

Comment: The problem is, Glitch uses `git` in order to upload files from your computer. Are you suggesting I make a Github Release and then use something like a Github Action to automatically push it to Glitch?

Comment: Not having used Glitch, nor GitHub Actions, I can't say anything about those. It's just that I think Git submodules are inherently wrong (the klunkiness around them being an artifact of this wrongness) and hence any solution that uses submodules is ... sub-optimal, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235634/discussion-between-megargayu-and-torek).

Comment: Even though I never ended up using this answer, I'm going to accept it for other people to find. I ended up making a GitHub workflow that automatically builds and pushes to Glitch after I push to GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

1. To ignore the specific folder/files, yes by using .gitignore file
2. To push specific folder/ "sub" git repository to different repository is by initialized new git on that specific folder, by running "git init" and "git remote add".

Example:

```
git init
git add somefile
git commit -m "initial commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/new_repo
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop thinking about repository boundaries as anything substantial. The *only* important structure in Git is the history.

```bash
rm -rf build
git branch build $(git commit-tree -m 'Glitch project' `git mktree <&-`)
git worktree add build
git add build   # you'll get a newbie warning here
git remote add glitch u://r/l
git config remote.glitch.push  +refs/heads/build:refs/heads/build
```

and don't push the `build` branch to your main repo, you don't want that history there so don't push it there.

```bash
git config remote.origin.push :   # this is "matching", see the docs
git config remote.origin.push --add ^refs/heads/build  # don't match this
```

and now after a build completes and you like it enough to publish,

```bash
git -C build add .
git -C build commit -m "built $(date)"
git add build
git push glitch
```

When you clone from your github repo you'll get the history with a `build` entry in it, and checkout will create an empty directory there, but you won't have the `build` history itself. That's okay: if you want it, you can fetch it from someplace that does have it and then `git worktree add` it, or you can just not bother, `git init build` and redo the build locally.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> "*only*" might seem a bit strong, but it's really not. Everything else is support, scaffolding, infrastructure, just there to help with inspecting, analyzing, extending history.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Use .gitignore file in the root and add the files you don’t wanna push to GH

Comment: Okay, but then how would I configure the submodules? I'm a bit confused about that, so could you please explain/give an example?